# The def fields are zeros for my ebpf map in the ebpf obj file

Tags: maps, field, elf, sections, ebpf

I am playing a simple ebpf with the map definition as follows:

```
struct event {
    char comm[TASK_COMM_LEN];
    pid_t pid;
    uid_t uid;
};
struct {
    __uint(type, BPF_MAP_TYPE_HASH);
    __uint(max_entries, 128);
    __type(key, pid_t);
    __type(value, struct event);
} execs_1 SEC(".maps");
```

when I load the corresponding elf obj file using https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.14.2/source/samples/bpf/bpf_load.c, I saw correct map name as 'execs_1'. But when I was trying to get the map definition, all fields are just zero. See line 421 in the link. Basically, I am curious the bpf info kept in the corresponding elf obj file. I checked the corresponding code https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/tools/lib/bpf/libbpf.c at line 2026. It seems that there is no diff. Any comments on how to get the field info of the map from elf bpf object file:

```
struct bpf_map_def {
    unsigned int type;
    unsigned int key_size;
    unsigned int value_size;
    unsigned int max_entries;
    unsigned int map_flags;
    unsigned int inner_map_idx;
    unsigned int numa_node;
};
```

Thanks.

Comment: It seems that the info is fetched in the function parse_btf_map_def, right?

Comment: Could you share your code?

Comment: What do you mean, “trying to get the map definition”, do you mean that with `bpftool map list` the key/value size and max entries are all at 0? Your link points to 4.14.2, it's an old kernel for eBPF development. Is it the `bpf_load.c` version you're using? I'm pretty sure the syntax you're using to declare maps was not supported at the time.

Comment: “trying to get the map definition” means retrieving all info prepared for the sys_bpf(BPF_MAP_CREATE,...) call. Specifically, it includes the members of the struct bpf_map_def such as map_type, key_size, max_entries, map_flags.   Yes. I did notice that bpf_load.c is old and not updated. Another question is that how we can get the definition of 'struct event' from the elf obj file. I am thinking to create a 'map' to simulate the behavior in the kernel. May I assume that all the map info is stored in BTF of the elf obj file? if it is true, which section is it? Thanks.